# How can I setup website on my router without internet?

Tags: routes, connection, wifi

I want to setup a website on my wifi router which can be accessed by anyone who is connected to my router using some link like `172.XXX.XXX.XXX`.

Comment: Well unless your router has a user customisable web server (highly unlikely) you can't.  You would run a web server on a machine on the network and local users would access that.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a port forwarding rule in your router,
setting IP (of pc hosting website) and Port (in this case should be 80).

This way you can access website by router ip address.